# google maps store locator modify hardcoded initialization to dynamic

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, this, typeerror

I'm trying to modify this example
http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/panel.html

the javascript code is here:
https://gist.github.com/2725336

the aspect I'm having difficulties with is changing this:

```
MedicareDataSource.prototype.FEATURES_ = new storeLocator.FeatureSet(
  new storeLocator.Feature('Wheelchair-YES', 'Wheelchair access'),
  new storeLocator.Feature('Audio-YES', 'Audio')
);
```

to create the FeatureSet from a function, so for example I have this function which parses a JSON object

```
WPmmDataSource.prototype.setFeatures_ = function(json) {
    var features = [];

    // convert features JSON to js object
    var rows = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

    // iterate through features collection
    jQuery.each(rows, function(i, row){

    var feature = new storeLocator.Feature(row.slug + '-YES', row.name)

    features.push(feature);
    });

    return  new storeLocator.FeatureSet(features);
    };
```

so then change the first code snippet to something like

```
WPmmDataSource.prototype.FEATURES_ = this.setFeatures_(wpmm_features);
```

which returns an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'setFeatures_'
```

Comment: I put a demo of this here: http://demo.wpconsult.net/ you can see the error messages in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to make some changes to the `WPmmDataSource.prototype` and your `setFeatures_` method:

```
WPmmDataSource.prototype = {
    FEATURES_ : null,        
    setFeatures_ : function( json ) {
        //Set up an empty FEATURES_ FeatureSet
        this.FEATURES_ = new storeLocator.FeatureSet();
        //avoid the use of "this" within the jQuery loop by creating a local var
        var featureSet = this.FEATURES_;
        // convert features JSON to js object
        var rows = jQuery.parseJSON( json );
        // iterate through features collection
        jQuery.each( rows, function( i, row ) {
            featureSet.add(
                new storeLocator.Feature( row.slug + '-YES', row.name ) );
        });
    }
}
```

And with this, you don't have to do the assignment by returning a value from `setFeatures_`; it has direct access to the `FEATURES_` member. So the line:

```
WPmmDataSource.prototype.FEATURES_ = this.setFeatures_(wpmm_features);
```

is no longer necessary. This also means that later, when you have created an instance of `WPmmDataSource`, your code can work like this:

```
var wpmd = new WPmmDataSource( /* whatever options, etc. you want */ );
wpmd.setFeatures_( json );
// Thereafter, wpmd will have its FEATURES_ set
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but I believe this will get you over the hurdle of your current stall. I hope this gets you moving forward -

Comment: thanks, but FEATURES_ needs to be accessible to the class methods, as you see it is being used to assign features to the stores in the parse_ function.
If I use your code, the features.add(this.FEATURES_.getById('Wheelchair-' + row.Wheelchair));
function throws an error on getById because FEATURES_ is undefined.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure. Glad to help. I have made an adjustment to the code above to correctly create `FEATURES_` and make sure it is available to all methods in the `WPmmDataSource` JavaScript class.

Comment: thanks Sean, I finally figured it out with your help. Appreciate the effort. I just had to save FEATURES_ to a variable in the parse_ function to get it to finally work.